# How to play an Alpha video inside an Unlit sphere in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, alpha, google-vr, 360-virtual-reality

I'm trying to play an Alpha Video inside a sphere which has a StereoPanoSphereMaterial using a shader "GoogleVR/Demo/VideoDemo InsideShader" and is used to play a 360 degree video.
I'm using a GoogleVR/Unlit/TransparentOVerlay shader on a Quad to run my Alpha Video inside the sphere. It appears to be running fine when I run it in the editor but when I run it on my device it just shows a blank Quad which is supposed to be transparent and the video cannot be seen as well.
I've tried playing it with other given shaders as well like FX/Flare, Unlit/Transparent to no use.
Any tips on how to play an Alpha video inside my 360 degree video sphere?

[image: Game View in the Editor]
Game View in the Editor

[image: Scene View in the Editor]
Scene View in the Editor

[image: View on Phone]
View on Phone

Comment: Unity does not support video texture on mobile devices. You will need to acquire a 3rd party asset from the asset store.

Comment: I changed the format of the video from .mov to .webm and it seems to be working for now..
And I've been using GVR Video Texture for a while now.. That's working fine to play both 360 degree and rectangular videos for VR.. Although I don't see the video playing in the editor but it plays fine on the mobile device.. I think there must be some exceptions to that case..

Comment: If you're using a plugin, then it's going to have different limitations than Unity native and each plugin will work on some subset of "all devices" (noting of course that "all devices" is a set that is a subset of "all devices", although finding a plugin that actually *does* support everything is hard).

Comment: Can you suggest some other assets/plugins to play alpha videos in my VR application without much problem?

Comment: Try [this one](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10032), it's on sale and has a decent chunk of supported platforms (including android).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for anybody following this thread. The problem is that GVR SDK apparently do not support .mov format as of now even when Unity does. So we converted the video in a .webm format and it is working not to the best of our expectations but does the job of playing the Alpha Videos inside the sphere playing the stereoscopic video for now.
Also note that out of the shaders present in default with Unity only FX/Flare shader works well with this format to play videos in VR.
P.S. I also tried to place a PNG image as a component inside the view, even that is not working for now, even when it works in Unity.